# Meteor color hints at chemistry

Tags: chemistry, entry-descent-landing, meteors

This recent meteor over the midwest. Reports described it at blue / green. I have seen blue / white, red and yellow meteors. I presume red means iron, green means copper. Can meteoritics or meteor specialists (or whatever you call them) say a lot about the content of a meteor based or the color it makes during entry?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Absolutely, it's the same as heating up metals with a blowtorch. The colour of the flame tells you what is present. Wikipedia actually has a [handy list](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meteoroid) giving an indication of the significant elements present:

- Orange-yellow (sodium)
- Yellow (iron)
- Blue-green (magnesium)
- Violet (calcium)

And

- Red (atmospheric nitrogen and oxygen)

Comment: Spectrography can provide some more hints.

Comment: Absolutely - but as a handy guide for anyone looking up, this works. I'm unlikely to ever have spectrographic analysis kit with me when metero spotting :-)

Comment: Of course if there is *more than a single element* contributing to the color, you're in a pickle. If you have yellow & violet, or orange & blue they may give the impression of no color.

Comment: If it's similar to flame tests of metal ion containing compounds, shouldn't magnesium correspond to a white flame?